# Body set up to 100vh is taking more than 100% of the viewport?

Tags: css

I hope you have a nice day.

Today I came to a strange thing.
When I set the body to 100vh, it is supposed to take the height of the viewport, the screen height.

But when I create multiple elements with bigger height than my body and set their background to transparent, I still see my body under them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.overflow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="home"></div>
<div class="overflow"></div>
```

You also have this codepen if you want to visualize it.
https://codepen.io/Ziratsu/pen/ExjMpyO

Can someone explain to me why the body is still here while we scroll to another div who is supposed to overflow the body height ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It works perfectly on my screen with chrome .. i can't see your problem, could you please add a screen-shoot ?

Comment: Just scroll down and you'll see the black color of the body underneath the blue one.
But the body is supposed to be 100vh, not 200vh!

Comment: html{background:something} --> it's background propagation, you need to set a background to html element to avoid this